# SWIG: Wrap call to C++ method with custom code?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm trying to use SWIG directors to call Python code from C++. However if the code is running in another thread, I must acquire the GIL. My code looks roughly like this (minus the thread stuff):

```
struct Callback {
  virtual ~Callback() {}
  virtual void call() {} // will be overwritten in Python
};

struct Foo {
    Callback *c;
    Foo(Callback* c) : c(c) {}
    void doSomething() { c->call(); } // being called from another thread
};
```

Python:

```
from demo import *
class MyCallback(Callback):
    def call(*args):
        print("python callback")

c = MyCallback()
f = Foo(c)
f.doSomething()
```

Swig:

```
%module(directors="1", threads="1") demo
%feature("director");

%{
#include <test.h>
%}
%thread;
%include <test.h>
```

How can I acquire the GIL before calling the Python callback?

To elaborate, the `threads` feature of SWIG creates code that releases the GIL when C++ code is called, but when Python code is called from C++ it isn't reacquired, so that's what I want to do.

The call stack looks like this: Python -> `Foo.doSomething` -> C++ -> `Callback.call` -> Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acquiring the GUIL is explained clearly in [Non-Python created threads](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads) subsection of *Thread State and the Global Interpreter Lock* section in Python manual. But you say the issue is how to do this from SWIG generated code. How about this, added to your SWIG .i file:

```
struct PythonCallback: public Callback
{
  virtual void call() { 
     getGIL();
     lockedCall();
     releaseGIL();
  } 

  virtual void lockedCall() {} // will be overwritten in Python
};
```

You only need to expose `PythonCallback` (not Callback) and its `lockedCall` method, which you can rename to `call` if you wish via SWIG's `%rename` directive. Then in Python you would derive from `PythonCallback`, and override the `call` method (which in reality is the `lockedCall` method if you `%rename`'d it).

Comment: This is not an answer. If you want to comment on the question, please use the comments section.

Comment: My problem isn't that I don't know *how* to acquire the GIL, that would have nothing to do with SWIG. My problem is how to integrate that into SWIG directors, so that it's acquired before the SWIG director calls a Python method.

Comment: It didn't work when I added it to the SWIG file, but in a separate header file it did. Unfortunately it looks like there is no way to do this with a generic macro instead of writing this by hand every time.